# How to limit the mysql records on the basis of a column value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to limit the records on the basis of usernames(column) in my table i.e if my limit is 5 then fetch all the records of the first 5 usernames only. There can be multiple records for any usernames. I also want to be able to use the concept of offset so that next time I can fetch other 5 records.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And take a look at [mcve] too.

Comment: I guess you could have a subquery with LIMIT to return the first 5 usernames only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following :

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE username IN (SELECT DISTINCT username FROM table ORDER BY username LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0)
```

Then later with offset :

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE username IN (SELECT DISTINCT username FROM table ORDER BY username LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5)
```

etc.

Of course you could add an order by for the main query like "ORDER BY username" if you want to sort the final results.

Comment: Glad to have helped you, therefore you can accept this answer as solution